# Using Tampermonkey Chrome to loop jquery code that "automatically clicks a specific button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, button

Update: The actual code and interval functions work, however I still cannot get it to behave properly as a tampermonky script. The console will spit out errors for characters that aren't even part of the script. **So the only thing I need to get working in either chrome as an extension or a tampermonkey userscript and I'd be one happy camper.**

Here's the error I receive:

```
Syntax error @ '********.com Auto Clicker'!
##########################
JSHINT output:
require: (E030) Expected an identifier and instead saw '<' on line: 2 at character: 1
require: (E033) Expected an operator and instead saw '!' on line: 2 at character: 2
require: (W030) Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on line: 2 at character: 2
require: (W033) Missing semicolon on line: 2 at character: 3
require: (W030) Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on line: 2 at character: 3
require: (W033) Missing semicolon on line: 2 at character: 10
require: (E030) Expected an identifier and instead saw '<' on line: 3 at character: 1
require: (E033) Expected an operator and instead saw '!' on line: 3 at character: 2
require: (E033) Expected an operator and instead saw '--' on line: 3 at character: 3
require: (E033) Expected an operator and instead saw '[' on line: 3 at character: 5
require: (E041) Unrecoverable syntax error. (0% scanned) on line: 3 at character: 6
##########################

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Function (native)
at d (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:27:37)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source)), <anonymous>:1:24)
at eval (native)
at m (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:53:418)
at Z (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:27:80)
at aa (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:63:497)
at chromeEmu.extension.onMessage.addListener.b (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:64:398)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:31:339)(anonymous function) @ VM1109:28Context.chromeEmu.f.runResponse @ VM1109:13(anonymous function) @ VM1120:1(anonymous function) @ VM1120:1copy.exec @ VM1106:1copy.Eventing.d @ VM1106:8copy.Eventing.c.eventHandlerPage @ VM1106:12c.standardEventSource.element.dispatchEvent @ content.js:22c.fireEvent @ content.js:24g.sendMessage @ content.js:8d.onResponse @ content.js:16(anonymous function) @ content.js:18messageListener @ extensions::messaging:352propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:395propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:379EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:401propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19$Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:316
```

*Original: So I am currently fiddling around with a small project; which has been asked many times I am aware but after searching Google, this site, etc. for a few hours I must say I am completely stumped. I currently have*

*This has been updated based upon some comments below.*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         *******.com Auto Clicker
// @version      0.1
// @description  Made this for fun, simply clicks for you on *******.com
// @author       Cole Smith
// @match        *********************
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval(function(){ 
    if ($(timerValue).hasClass("timer hide")) {
        $('a.btn.btn-small.button_next.btn-advance').click();
   } 
},1000);
```

**The stars are obfuscations.** *Except the star after JQuery, as I just want it to require any version.*

I just want it to be active on the page and continue to do so in a repeating fashion. If I could disable it with a key stroke within chrome that would be nice but it isn't something I am too concerned about at the moment.

Notes:
I do have @match set, it will show as enabled on the site within the tampermonkey extension but will **NOT** run even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your *@require* to load jQuery and not the website. The current statement causes the HTML of http://code.jquery.com/jquery* to be interpreted as Javascript. That causes the

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

error message. So the solution is to change this line to:

```
// @require    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

Comment: Maybe I was incorrect. Hold on; there seems to be more than one error here. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: changed answer after establishing goal of code.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    if ($(timerValue).hasClass("hide")) {
        $('a.btn.btn-small.button_next.btn-advance').click();
    } 
},500); //change 500 to the time in MS to wait before each run.
```

Comment: I guess I should also note there's a timer before you can click ahead, and the page changes the close "timer hide" from "timer."

Comment: Maybe using an interval to call the click set to the timer time (+100ms to be safe) would work then ?

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect disabling and re-enabling the script when the button is available. The If statement works fine by itself pasted into chrome's console, any given point (when the id timerValue has the class "timer hide" that is. But always works when the conditions are met.) How does simply encapsulating it within a function, also of which (unless I am missing something) doesn't have a name I can call later makes this both consistently check and run the function and the code within on a loop? Could you explain _how_ this answers my question? Knowledge is power.

Comment: Way over my head, I really haven't touched this since codecademy a while ago. How do I use an "interval?"

Comment: I'm on mobile so I miss read your question, I thought you wanted it to run on load and that function will only fire when the page is ready. I'd put the loop inside that function.

Comment: That will run every time the interval is up

Comment: So looking at the console when I refresh the page it seems for some reason it just hits a wall, but the script doesn't contain these characters?

`Syntax error @ '**Obfuscated**.com Auto Clicker'!
##########################
JSHINT output:
require: (E030) Expected an identifier and instead saw '<' on line: 2 at character: 1`

Followed by many others

Comment: Posted the new code, updated the question. Used your updated answer to begin with, but with no avail.

Comment: if you put the interval into the console does it click for you every 1s correctly ?

Comment: what is 'timerValue' ? you have never set this variable

Comment: That's the sites id, its not a class or var as far as I am aware. Ignore anything having to do with it other than making it loop. The code works